# How can i do server side paginations in jsgrid?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, jsgrid

Is there any way to so server side pagination with `jsgrid` ? I know we can do filtering data with server side, but not pagination ?

Comment: Pagination is best done with different SQL queries leaving it completely up to the database, `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` is used to get a smaller dataset

Comment: how to do it in jsgrid library in front-end, it manages pagination in client side . I want to know is it possible way in-built in JS library to server side pagination, by sending parameters to sever side.

Comment: Just pass the deseired parameters in your AJAX calls to the server, same way you pass user name and password, pass the pagination parameters that you will incorporate into the SQL query, you do not need a library to pass the parameters to the server, it's as simple as it gets. Making a client side pagination is what is more complex.

Comment: i think i get what i want to know from reading http://www.jqueryrain.com/?145gS1l1
there are  fields to set in the grid like pageIndex and pagesize.
anyway thanks @Dellirium

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, server-side pagination is the basic scenario for jsgrid.

Use the config option `pageLoading: true`.

In this case the controller method `loadData(filter)` will accept `pageIndex` and `pageSize`. You should pass these params to the server script. Returning result should have format `{ data: [array of items on the current page], itemsCount: [totalAmountOfItems]}`.

http://js-grid.com/docs/#loaddatafilter-promisedataresult

Checkout this issue on GitHub to get more details

- https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/175
- https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/860

Comment: If you want to add server pagination and you are using sort column filters too, you have to implement also server side sorting, using the sortField and sortOrder.